# Missing where_id in structures/<structure-id>/wheres

Tags: nest-api

For one of the homes my app is connecting to using the Nest REST API, the where location assigned to one of the cameras is not listed in the wheres list.  I’m not 100% sure but I believe the where location in question, ‘Front Yard’, is a built-in one that was recently added to accommodate outdoor cams.  The where_id for ‘Front Yard' is L5K8ePT_SA_xeABp03h9LOH2J3gR2sjE58zxotSsFrnCbIQ0AQRHSg and for reference the complete wheres list is cut/paste below.

All of this works fine using the web app from a browser and the iOS app on on iPad/iPhone but clearly something is out of sync when using the REST API.  My app only has write permission for home/away so I’m pretty I didn’t introduce the inconsistency.

Thanks,
Kevin

{'L5K8ePT_SA_xeABp03h9LOH2J3gR2sjE58zxotSsFrnHRs9CoUFwCQ': {'where_id': 'L5K8ePT_SA_xeABp03h9LOH2J3gR2sjE58zxotSsFrnHRs9CoUFwCQ', 'name': 'Bedroom'}, 'L5K8ePT_SA_xeABp03h9LOH2J3gR2sjE58zxotSsFrk6bmlW6JPIKw': {'where_id': 'L5K8ePT_SA_xeABp03h9LOH2J3gR2sjE58zxotSsFrk6bmlW6JPIKw', 'name': 'Den'}, 'xqmEMyhCen8FHEmFxOo5jX3RWobmscu6zBBr8pdu-veIYbhrFjxNNw': {'where_id': 'xqmEMyhCen8FHEmFxOo5jX3RWobmscu6zBBr8pdu-veIYbhrFjxNNw', 'name': 'Garage'}, 'L5K8ePT_SA_xeABp03h9LOH2J3gR2sjE58zxotSsFrlcNa-V3WRJAA': {'where_id': 'L5K8ePT_SA_xeABp03h9LOH2J3gR2sjE58zxotSsFrlcNa-V3WRJAA', 'name': 'Basement'}, 'L5K8ePT_SA_xeABp03h9LOH2J3gR2sjE58zxotSsFrnH3br5CDnsKA': {'where_id': 'L5K8ePT_SA_xeABp03h9LOH2J3gR2sjE58zxotSsFrnH3br5CDnsKA', 'name': 'Family Room'}, 'kJ71hVxi0hJ7zUo4TzUu3jfQLd6yPtBMx696H_tumzUUcK_3VLe0Ew': {'where_id': 'kJ71hVxi0hJ7zUo4TzUu3jfQLd6yPtBMx696H_tumzUUcK_3VLe0Ew', 'name': 'Back Yard'}, 'L5K8ePT_SA_xeABp03h9LOH2J3gR2sjE58zxotSsFrmJPnCH5smMUg': {'where_id': 'L5K8ePT_SA_xeABp03h9LOH2J3gR2sjE58zxotSsFrmJPnCH5smMUg', 'name': 'Hallway'}, 'd44aSYTfLVEYmcfI0Jwcz9G2uazXEmUfl_YzwLu1l37V6xivkkk1KA': {'where_id': 'd44aSYTfLVEYmcfI0Jwcz9G2uazXEmUfl_YzwLu1l37V6xivkkk1KA', 'name': 'West Yard'}, 'L5K8ePT_SA_xeABp03h9LOH2J3gR2sjE58zxotSsFrlQnDUuljAWbw': {'where_id': 'L5K8ePT_SA_xeABp03h9LOH2J3gR2sjE58zxotSsFrlQnDUuljAWbw', 'name': 'Downstairs'}, 'L5K8ePT_SA_xeABp03h9LOH2J3gR2sjE58zxotSsFrkuLsLZUeH-3A': {'where_id': 'L5K8ePT_SA_xeABp03h9LOH2J3gR2sjE58zxotSsFrkuLsLZUeH-3A', 'name': 'Master Bedroom'}, 'L5K8ePT_SA_xeABp03h9LOH2J3gR2sjE58zxotSsFrkn2yuSZHKulg': {'where_id': 'L5K8ePT_SA_xeABp03h9LOH2J3gR2sjE58zxotSsFrkn2yuSZHKulg', 'name': 'Living Room'}, '6M1qTQskUQFmQUL_QoHu-JGKdJwkoG6MZ4Bu7OsKYL-JOUQSRhhcRA': {'where_id': '6M1qTQskUQFmQUL_QoHu-JGKdJwkoG6MZ4Bu7OsKYL-JOUQSRhhcRA', 'name': 'Upstairs Hallway'}, 'L5K8ePT_SA_xeABp03h9LOH2J3gR2sjE58zxotSsFrmFL6Eiqigsmw': {'where_id': 'L5K8ePT_SA_xeABp03h9LOH2J3gR2sjE58zxotSsFrmFL6Eiqigsmw', 'name': 'Kids Room'}, 'L5K8ePT_SA_xeABp03h9LOH2J3gR2sjE58zxotSsFrmltcwKgm79iQ': {'where_id': 'L5K8ePT_SA_xeABp03h9LOH2J3gR2sjE58zxotSsFrmltcwKgm79iQ', 'name': 'Upstairs'}, 'L5K8ePT_SA_xeABp03h9LOH2J3gR2sjE58zxotSsFrn_59qioWdi-Q': {'where_id': 'L5K8ePT_SA_xeABp03h9LOH2J3gR2sjE58zxotSsFrn_59qioWdi-Q', 'name': 'Entryway'}, '3BBZNJp4tlkXpM3anwwpcnSl9t3Lqljagf0znxFq96PYyUG5_-HNGg': {'where_id': '3BBZNJp4tlkXpM3anwwpcnSl9t3Lqljagf0znxFq96PYyUG5_-HNGg', 'name': 'Guest Bedroom'}, 'fOdDlUl68hSiHsjDuNisUtq1Dq8p_SYabum4CUGUlkzJAFzMIMrgTA': {'where_id': 'fOdDlUl68hSiHsjDuNisUtq1Dq8p_SYabum4CUGUlkzJAFzMIMrgTA', 'name': 'Mud Room'}, 'L5K8ePT_SA_xeABp03h9LOH2J3gR2sjE58zxotSsFrnACVy3F3e5BA': {'where_id': 'L5K8ePT_SA_xeABp03h9LOH2J3gR2sjE58zxotSsFrnACVy3F3e5BA', 'name': 'Kitchen'}, '2ZK4PvWgSljwwW947D9XkLej0b7wtvDJvGG4sM_3dvEub7BoZW2Y1Q': {'where_id': '2ZK4PvWgSljwwW947D9XkLej0b7wtvDJvGG4sM_3dvEub7BoZW2Y1Q', 'name': 'East Yard'}, 'L5K8ePT_SA_xeABp03h9LOH2J3gR2sjE58zxotSsFrmGc1UwaBS6nQ': {'where_id': 'L5K8ePT_SA_xeABp03h9LOH2J3gR2sjE58zxotSsFrmGc1UwaBS6nQ', 'name': 'Office'}, 'L5K8ePT_SA_xeABp03h9LOH2J3gR2sjE58zxotSsFrlrBwYMB0Ma5Q': {'where_id': 'L5K8ePT_SA_xeABp03h9LOH2J3gR2sjE58zxotSsFrlrBwYMB0Ma5Q', 'name': 'Dining Room'}}

Comment: what is your question? Please provide details and what you tried.

Comment: No question per se, just a possible bug report and hoping for someone from Nest to review and comment.  For every where_id assigned to a device there must be a corresponding entry in the wheres list and that's not happening.  In this case the where location was assigned from the iOS app and that all looks good but the corresponding view from the REST API is out of sync.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like Nest has populated the new built-in where items - the "Front Yard" entry is now in the wheres list:

'L5K8ePT_SA_xeABp03h9LOH2J3gR2sjE58zxotSsFrnCbIQ0AQRHSg': {'name': 'Front Yard', 'where_id': 'L5K8ePT_SA_xeABp03h9LOH2J3gR2sjE58zxotSsFrnCbIQ0AQRHSg'},